# Warning: JACC: For the URL pattern xxx, all but the following methods were uncovered: POST, GET

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, jaas, java-ee-7, servlet-3.1

In [`javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.html) docs, it is mentioned,

> **Allowable HTTP Methods**
>
> The JSF specification only requires the use of the GET and POST http
>   methods. If your web application does not require any other http
>   methods, such as PUT and DELETE, please consider restricting the
>   allowable http methods using the `<http-method>` and
>   `<http-method-omission>` elements. Please see the Security of the Java
>   Servlet Specification for more information the use of these elements.

---

My application indeed does not depend upon other HTTP methods (except `GET` and `POST`). Therefore, I am trying to use `<http-method>` (or `<http-method-omission>`) to exclude all methods except `GET` and `POST`.

In web.xml, <s>JAAS</s> Servlet security constraints are configured as follows.

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>AdminConstraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>ROLE_ADMIN</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/admin_side/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>ROLE_ADMIN</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description/>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>UserConstraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>ROLE_USER</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/user_side/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>ROLE_USER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description/>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Using these elements,

```xml
<http-method>GET</http-method>
<http-method>POST</http-method>
```

I expect that all other HTTP methods are disallowed.

---

The GlassFish Server 4.1 however, logs the following warnings on the server terminal.

> Warning:   JACC: For the URL pattern `/user_side/*`, all but the
>   following methods were uncovered: POST, GET
>
> Warning:   JACC: For the URL pattern `/admin_side/*`, all but the
>   following methods were uncovered: POST, GET

What does it mean?

---

Also instead of doing it in all `<security-constraint>` elements, can this be configured globally so that it can be applied to all resources in an application and that all except `GET` and `POST` HTTP requests can be omitted i.e. applied globally to an application - perhaps by using a more <s>generalized</s> specialized url-pattern like `/*`?

---

There is an example [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/nithya/entry/new_security_features_in_glassfish).

> ```
> <security-constraint>
>     <display-name>WebConstraint</display-name>
>
>     <web-resource-collection>
>         <web-resource-name>test</web-resource-name>
>         <description/>
>         <url-pattern>/test.jsp</url-pattern>
>         <http-method>POST</http-method>
>         <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
>         <http-method>PUT</http-method>
>         <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
>         <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
>         <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
>     </web-resource-collection>
>
>     <auth-constraint>
>         <description/>
>         <role-name>dev</role-name>
>      </auth-constraint>
> </security-constraint>
> ```
>
> the above element indicates that the  resource referenced by the url
>   pattern /test.jsp, when accessed by all the http-methods except GET  ,
>   should be constrained to be viewed only by authenticated users
>   belonging to the role dev. **Please note that the security constraint
>   does not apply for  the http-method GET, but only for the other
>   methods (POST, HEAD, PUT, etc).**

I found the last sentence in strong text confusing. Does it mean that using a `GET` request, resources listed in the given url-pattern are **also** accessible by **anonymous users** because it means to say, "***the security constraint*** does not apply for the http-method GET"?

Comment: >`JAAS security constraints are configured as follows.` - those are not JAAS security constraints, but Servlet security constraints.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What does it mean?

It means that all methods except GET and POST are uncovered, means unprotected. Everyone can access the url pattern `/user_side/*` with methods like PUT and HEAD without authentication.

To protect the other methods add the following:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>protected</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/user_side/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method-omission>GET</http-method-omission>
        <http-method-omission>POST</http-method-omission>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
</security-constraint>
```

If you are using Servlet 3.1 you can also use the shorter tag:

```xml
<deny-uncovered-http-methods/>
```

> Also instead of doing it in all  elements, can
>   this be configured globally so that it can be applied to all resources
>   in an application and that all except GET and POST HTTP requests can
>   be omitted i.e. applied globally to an application - perhaps by using
>   a more generalized url-pattern like /*?

Yes, this is possible. You can use the url-pattern `/` to include all subfolders.

> I found the last sentence in strong text confusing. Does it mean that
>   using a GET request, resources listed in the given url-pattern can
>   also be accessible by anonymous users because it means to say, "the
>   security constraint does not apply for the http-method GET"?

You are right, it means that anonymous user can access the given url-pattern with the GET method. All other methods are protected.

**See also:**

- [security-constraint url-pattern and the * character within web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705846/security-constraint-url-pattern-and-the-character-within-web-xml)
- [Exclude css & image resources in web.xml Security Constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696204/exclude-css-image-resources-in-web-xml-security-constraint)

Comment: I used `<deny-uncovered-http-methods/>`, since I am on Servlet 3.1. The log level was lowered to `INFO` and different massages were logged after these changes were made like : `Info: JACC: For the URL pattern /user_side/*, all but the following methods have been excluded: POST,GET`. I assume that this is a safe message and that I have done everything correctly :) Good findings. Thanks.