# Severe security constraints while tomcat 8 startup with liferay

Tags: security, tomcat, liferay, liferay-6, tomcat8

I am getting the below severe message while the tomcat 8 comes up with liferay.

```
SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityConstraint.findUncoveredHttpMethods For security constraints with URL pattern [/bg/c/portal/protected] only the HTTP methods [POST GET] are covered. All other methods are uncovered.
03-Sep-2015 07:06:00.733 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityConstraint.findUncoveredHttpMethods For security constraints with URL pattern [/sv/c/portal/protected] only the HTTP methods [POST GET] are covered. All other methods are uncovered.
03-Sep-2015 07:06:00.733 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityConstraint.findUncoveredHttpMethods For security constraints with URL pattern [/zh/c/portal/protected] only the HTTP methods [POST GET] are covered. All other methods are uncovered.
```

**This does not have any impact on server start up but not sure what is causing this? Any help would really appreciated.**

Comment: See also this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431243/warning-jacc-for-the-url-pattern-xxx-all-but-the-following-methods-were-uncov).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It means that in `web.xml` someone has specified a security constraint just for methods POST and GET on pattern `/bg/c/portal/protected`, possibly in a similar way to this:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/bg/c/portal/protected</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>...</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

You should either remove `http-method` brackets so it will match all methods for this `url-pattern` or create second one if you would like to set different security constraints on it without any `http-method` brackets.

For instance if you would like to secure with SSL `/bg/c/portal/protected` endpoint for the `POST` and `GET` methods, but for others you do not need that then you should create a config like this:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/bg/c/portal/protected</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/bg/c/portal/protected</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

As you see now all methods for this pattern are covered, hence no error will be thrown.