# SEVERE - For security constraints with URL pattern [/*] the HTTP methods [POST GET] are uncovered

Tags: servlets, web.xml

I am getting this error when I start Tomcat:

> SEVERE - For security constraints with URL pattern [/*] the HTTP
>   methods [POST GET] are uncovered.

**What is the reason of this?**

---

I think this is a different problem from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378884/severe-security-constraints-while-tomcat-8-startup-with-liferay).

My web.xml looks like:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict resources</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>/resources dir</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Whitelist</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method-omission>GET</http-method-omission>
        <http-method-omission>POST</http-method-omission>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

So I try to forbid all methods except `GET` and `POST` (see ). However, some methods (`PUT`, `DELETE`, `OPTIONS`...) seem to return a "`302 Found`" instead of an automatic `403`, not sure why (missing request parameters?).

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like you actually also forbid `GET` and `POST`. Instead of an empty `<auth-constraint />` in the second `<security-constraint>` section, try the following:

```
<auth-constraint>
  <role-name>*</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
```

Furthermore, you may need to add another "deny" section for the uncovered methods for `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`. However, if you are using Servlet 3.1+ (e.g. Tomcat 8.5.x), you can simply use this tag instead of another `<security-constraint>` section:

```
<deny-uncovered-http-methods />
```

Make sure then, that your `web.xml` actually does define Servlet 3.1, e.g.:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1"
  metadata-complete="true">
```